# convert struct to uint8_t array in C++

Tags: c++, linux, struct, buffer, uint8t

I have a typedef struct with different data types in it. The number array has negative and non-negative values. How do I convert this struct in to a unint8t array in C++ on the Linux platform. Appreciate some help on this. Thank you. The reason I am trying to do the conversation is to send this uint8_t buffer as a parameter to a function.

```
typedef struct
{
  int enable;
  char name;
  int numbers[5];
  float counter;
};
```

appreciate any example on doing this. thank you

Comment: By the way, why are you using `typedef` for your structure if you're programming in C++? That's not needed.

Comment: Oh, and a name with only a single letter? That won't even be able to hold a C-style null-terminated string, except the empty string (which have *only* the null-terminator).

Comment: What are you trying to solve, sending data over a network, save/load objects to disk?  You are entering the territory of binary serialization. Don't take anything for granted (and that includes the memory layout of your struct). And also don't assume it is always safe to cast that array back to a valid object (POD's should be fine)

Comment: I am trying to send the data over a tcp socket connection

Comment: In that case simply casting is fine - but your struct layout will have platform-specific endianness and padding which are not, in general, guaranteed to be the same as the recipient's.

Comment: Reinforcing Useless's comment, my project was "burned" by not properly serializing/deserializing `struct` objects that were going out over TCP/IP connections when our platform moved from DEC Alpha Tru64 UNIX to a mixed environment with Intel-based Windows NT machines as well.  Padding changed, endian-ness changed, and even `sizeof` some primitive types changed.  It was a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a [plain old data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) structure like the one you show this is trivial:

You know the size of the structure in bytes (from the `sizeof` operator).

That means you can create a vector of bytes of that size.

Once you have that vector you can copy the bytes of the structure object into the vector.

Now you have, essentially, an array of bytes representation of the structure object.

---

In code it would be something like this:

```
struct my_struct_type
{
    int enable;
    char name;
    int numbers[5];
    float counter;
};

my_struct_type my_struct_object = {
    // TODO: Some valid initialization here...
};

// Depending on the compiler you're using, and its C++ standard used
// you might need to use `std::uint8_t` instead of `std::byte`
std::vector<std::byte> bytes(sizeof my_struct_object);

std::memcpy(bytes.data(), reinterpret_cast<void*>(&my_struct_object), sizeof my_struct_object);
```

Comment: yes I know the size of the struct. How do I copy the bytes from the structure into the vector?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use `char*`. For that type, C++ allows you to cast any pointer to it and use `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj)`. (Assuming `Obj obj;`.)

If you need to use `uint8_t*` (and it's not a typedef to `char*`, you can allocate sufficient memory and do `memcpy`:

```
uint8_t buffer[sizeof(Obj)];
memcpy(buffer, &obj, sizeof(obj));
```

Comment: so once the bufffer is sent over the tcp socket how do I construct the struct on the server side. Appreciate an example

Comment: @jkafernando Same way, you just swap dest and src: data is in `buffer`, then `memcpy(&obj, buffer, sizeof(obj));`.